# OpenGL GLFW + GLAD Program cannot draw triangle

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glad

I'm trying to draw a triangle with GLFW and Glad.

But it doesn't display anything on screen.

I'm able to open window and make the screen to any Color but cannot draw triangle.

It show like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JR2i4.png)

I'm doing this program in Ubuntu22

(required lib are imported glad, glfw, math, iostream)

```
const char* vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"latout (location =0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"   gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);\n"
"}\0";
const char* fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"out vec4 FragColor;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"   FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);\n"
"}\n\0";

int main(){
    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    GLfloat vertices[] = 
    {
        -0.5, -0.5f * float(sqrt(3)) / 3, 0.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f * float(sqrt(3)) / 3, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.5f * float(sqrt(3)) * 2 / 3, 0.0f
    };

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(600, 600, "TriangleOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if(window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout<<"Failed to create GLFW window"<< std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    gladLoadGL();


    glViewport(0, 0, 600, 600);


    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);



    GLuint VAO, VBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);



    glClearColor(0.07f, 0.13f, 0.17f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClearColor(0.07f, 0.13f, 0.17f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not a GLSL expert but I think you have errors in your shaders.

Comment: ... typo: `latout` should be `layout `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax error in your vertex shader:

```
"latout (location =0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
```

It should be `layout (location = 0)`.

You can easily find it yourself if you add something like that after `glCompileShader`.

```
  GLint logLength;
  glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLength);
  if (logLength > 0)
  {
    GLchar *log = new GLchar[logLength];
    glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, logLength, &logLength, log);
    std::cout << log << std::endl;
    delete[] log;
  }
```